# File-names in web development: What shall one use as an word-separator in complex file names?

Tags: java, php

I ask myself what I shall use as an separator for complex files names like for example "Monthly Project Report".

I see a lot of people using hyphen. According: 'monthly-project.report.php'.

But I got some doubt concerning that because hyphen can be mistaken as an arithmetic minus in programming.

Wouldn't it be better to use an underscore (_)?

**So what separator in appropriate to use?**

Comment: underscore is very goot for readability in your files. just like `user_formular.php` the - and . can affect errors with some interpreters

Comment: Or you can use monthlyProjectReport.php like camel case convention. Usually most of MVC frameworks recommend this.

Comment: There's no "better" or "worse", you should use what makes sense to you (as long as it's not a forbidden character like `/ `). I've seen filenames with `-` and `_` as separators, those are the most common, but I've also seen some where the separator is `.` or `,`, I've even seen one with `^`.

Comment: have a look at this posts url: `file-names-in-web-development-what-shall-one-use-as-an-word-separator-in-comple` it uses the minus sign to replace the whitespace. That is pretty common for webpages. But that doesn't mean that you *sould* use it for your file names. More importantly: use one format that is easy for you to read and use it everywhere throughout the application. In Java for example it is common to user CamelCase (each word begins with a capital letter and  no whitespaces) e.g: `monthlyProjectReport.php` Nevertheless, don't mix.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 Yep. Effecting stuff. That's exactly what I'm afraid of. Nevertheless I see - a lot in web development. And that has made me wonder ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a problem. You better to use (*) If you not going to show the file in Google search engine. most of the developers normally use (-) for Google SEO targeting.
You should better use (*) as you mentioned some one may be have doubt if it is mines :)